# Displaying a warning if diagnostic plots hint to a publication bias in metafor package

Tags: r, shiny, metafor

I ran a meta-analysis in R using metafor package. I implemented it into an R shiny app, and displayed the diagnostic plots. How can I raise a "warning" in case the dots in our funnel plot fall out of the funnel, or show other not ideal behavior? Is there a way to make computer understand the funnel plots, and for example tell if the right and left-hand-side of the tunnel are not symmetric.

Please use the sample code below.

```
library(metafor)
 
### fit random-effects model
res <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
 
### create contour enhanced funnel plot (with funnel centered at 0)
funnel(res, level=c(90, 95, 99), shade=c("white", "gray55", "gray75"), refline=0, legend=TRUE)
```

Comment: Working out if any of your observed data fall "outside the funnel" is a matter of simple algebra.  "Not symmetric" needs more precise definition.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.